# Installing Laravel on Win 7

Tags: laravel

I'm running Win7 32 bit, XAMPP

I have followed all the instructions on Laravel website, Composer is now running on my PC but could not install Laravel. I got hooked when I tried running this command "composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist"

it keeps on showing "Could not open input file: C:\xampp\php\composer.pharcreate-project"

How will I solve this problem

Comment: Try typing `composer -V` to see if you can actually call composer commands. Otherwise, you may need to add it to you  `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis, I tried running composer -v but the command is not running. I guess that is the problem, I have also tried to solve the problem but to no avail, I hope you could help me further. earnestly waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you need to CD to the location where you want to create your LARAVEL project.

Since you are running windows if you did install composer with shell menu enabled, you can just right-click on the folder and click use composer here.

Then `composer create-project laravel/laravel`  should do the trick.